# magento 2 credit memo quantity fields not editable

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to refund one of the 3 items ordered, when creating a credit memo I can only make a credit memo for the whole order. The qty fields are not editable.

In the old version this was not a problem.

I found out that changing code below can solve the problem, but in which file.

```
protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial = true;
```

Please provide me with a solution or the file I can change to make partial credit memo possible